# "conversely" vs. "whereas"

Tags: difference

Tell me please if I can replace the word *conversely* with the word *whereas*.

> Kate likes cats, converesely(whereas) John likes dogs.

It seems those words are synonymous, but the *Meriam Webster* and *Oxford* dictionaries do not say that they are, so I am confused.

Comment: They are not synonyms. Converse comes from logic: Dogs like cats: the converse is: Cats like dogs. Whereas is a conjunction, like but.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Conversely" and "whereas" do not mean the same thing.

"Conversely" expresses the idea that you are stating the opposite of what was just said.  For example:
*"Americans typically prefer coffee over tea.  Conversely, British prefer tea over coffee."*

"Whereas" has many definitions and uses.  It is most often a conjunction that is used to offset the difference between two things---sometimes very similar things:
*"A bicycle has two wheels, whereas a tricycle has three."*